# MOXy jaxb binding error for redefine element

Tags: exception, dynamic, jaxb, redefine

Can any one help me ?
In my project, I need to pares some schema files, and need to generate xml files base on these schemas. Now ,I want to user MOXy to generate empty xml files base on these schemas dynamicly.But exception happened.

```
Internal Exception: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: "file:/F:/workspace/test/src/custom2.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/F:/workspace/test/src/custom.xsd"?
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException.errorCreatingDynamicJAXBContext(JAXBException.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata.SchemaMetadata$XJCErrorListener.error(SchemaMetadata.java:235)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.error(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:316)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:628)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:619)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:262)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:391)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:146)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:108)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:442)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:230)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata.SchemaMetadata.getJavaModelInput(SchemaMetadata.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext.initializeFromMetadata(DynamicJAXBContext.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(DynamicJAXBContextFactory.java:345)
    ... 2 more
```

I think the reason is the redefine element, because when I use import or include,it's ok. Please help me. Can't upload attachement to stackoverflow?

Comment: I edit the code XMLSchemaInternalizationLogic, add redefine type to it , and this problem seems work now

Comment: how can I end the question?